# Sum a value in SSRS Reports based on date range

Tags: date, reporting-services, sum, range

I'm trying to sum a field value in an SSRS report based on a date range field in the same dataset, but have had no luck. So far this is what I've come up with. I've scoured the forums with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
= sum( iif(
            datediff("d",Fields!Calculated_DueDate.Value.value,today())>=31
    AND
      (datediff("d",Fields!Calculated_DueDate.Value,today())<62
         AND (Fields!Calculated_InvoiceBal.Value.value>0 ),
         Fields!Calculated_InvoiceBal.value,0)))
```

`Calculated_DueDate` is my date field and
`Calculated_InvoiceBal` is the field I want to sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first: you shouldn't use expression like `Fields!Calculated_DueDate.Value.value` - it is error.

The second: There are error in arrangement of brackets.

The third: In SSRS 2008R2 call of function `today()` marks as error. You can use expression `DateTime.Today` to get current date without errors markup.

So, your expression should look like this:

```
=sum( 
            iif(datediff("d",Fields!Calculated_DueDate.Value, DateTime.Today) >= 31                 
                            AND datediff("d",Fields!Calculated_DueDate.Value, DateTime.Today) < 62
                            AND (Fields!Calculated_InvoiceBal.Value > 0),
                    Fields!Calculated_InvoiceBal.value, 
                    0
                )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=SUM(IIf(datediff("d",Fields!Calculated_DueDate.Value.value,today())>=31 AND datediff("d",Fields!Calculated_DueDate.Value,today())<62 AND Fields!Calculated_InvoiceBal.Value.value>0), 
        Fields!Calculated_InvoiceBal.value, 0)
```

Comment: In what your expression differs from the original expression? It looks like you just change formatting.

Comment: Not the formatting so much as corrected your parentheses. You had more than you needed that were separating out the terms of your first IIf parameter, and then your second and third IIf parameters were incorrectly placed.

Comment: I'm sorry! I was not carefully studied your expression.

Comment: No worries. IIf statements can get really confusing, especially if you have a lot of terms you're looking at.